# Create a Table based on a Total and a Category from an Excel File

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an excel file with two Columns and 28664 Rows. Columns are Fuel and Power. I want to create a summary in a table of the total Power of each Fuel type. In other words, I want the Total for each fuel type. I started using Transpose to create a list containing each Fuel cell with its corresponding Power but I'm really stuck at this point. How can I create this summary?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "workbook1.xlsx"}], {"Data", 1}]
```

blank entries may be imported as empty strings so:

```
data[[All, 2]] = data[[All, 2]] /. _String -> 0;
```

then

```
GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Total]
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I put that output on a table or barchart?

Comment: Please at least try something before asking. `BarChart[GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Total]]` ????

Answer (score 4):

```
fuels = {"Coal", "Gas", "Hydro", "Nuclear", "Oil", "Other", "Wind"};

n = 50;
```

Generate random test data and [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) as Excel document

```
SeedRandom[0]

Export["data.xls", 
  Transpose[{RandomChoice[fuels, n], RandomReal[{0, 5000}, n]}]];
```

**You are starting here.** [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) data from Excel document

```
data = Import["data.xls"][[1]];
```

[`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) by fuel
**EDIT:** Added clean-up for blank values (issue identified by Mike Honeychurch)

```
summary = Sort[{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ GatherBy[data, First]]/. 
  Plus[x_?NumericQ, _. * _String] :> x

(* {{"Coal", 14230.6}, {"Gas", 11889.7}, {"Hydro", 20580.6}, {"Nuclear", 
  13221.4}, {"Oil", 14643.9}, {"Other", 17112.9}, {"Wind", 15121.8}} *)
```

**EDIT 2:** Added table

```
summary // Prepend[#, Style[#, Bold, 14] & /@ {"Fuel", "Power"}] & // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How can I put that output on a table?

Comment: Thanks! Everything worked perfectly.